# MQCC_FAILED : MQ reason=2003: MQRC_BACKED_OUT in topic in WebSphere MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

Our application is having one alias Queue(say 'Q') to one Topic(say 'T'); and application is "putting" or publishing the message to 'Q'.

In one scenario, the topic 'T' didn't received a message even if application successfully publishes the message to 'Q'.

i.e. in application [MessageProducer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html) sends the message to 'Q'via below call--

```
messageProducer.send(Message);
```

Now for above scenario, where 'T' didn't received message but application succeded to send it to 'Q' without any issue.(i.e. above `send` didn't throw any exception.)

We have checked the MQ logs and could see the errors for this as--

```
Error: MQ(Queue name): message refused: MQGET (MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG|MQGMO_SYNCPOINT|MQGMO_WAIT) failed MQCC_FAILED: [MQ reason=2003]: MQRC_BACKED_OUT
```

So any help why this error occured?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't your log files near full, or having a lot of uncommitted messages as this is happening?

Comment: Thanks @AttilaRepasi; for logs we may reach out to websphere guys; but how can we identify if there are lot of uncommitted messages? As number of messages publishing to the queues are very less-- you can say it's one messsage in a day.

Comment: Your WebSphere MQ admin can display qstatus to see if there are uncommitted messages (UNCOM attribute).    http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086260_.htm                                                                                          You could also do MQ trace to see when/if messages are being committed.